# How i can fix freeze cypress with test my app

Tags: cypress

Some times when i test my app with cypress , i have freeze and memory leak its eat all my memory.
in console i have error with style component.
"Cannot find a StyleSheet instance. Usually this happens if there are multiple copies of styled-components loaded at once." 
cant make screenshoot beacuse my pc frezee in this time.

my app on nodejs, test suite very simple.
how i can fix it? how i can close cypress if i have this memory leak?

```
cy.visit('/')
cy.scrollto(0,900)
cy.get('h1').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Cypress, it is currently being fixed: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2366